# Installing Pygame when I have 2 different Python versions installed

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I have two versions of python installed. 2.7 and 3.7.4. I want to install Pygame to 3.7 but am failing.

I've tried multiple tutorials and methods but no luck. Python 2.7 has all the files but 3.7 has only exes but still works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using pip, you could always try specifying the exact Python versions to install for:

```
$ python2.7 -m pip install pygame
$ python3.7 -m pip install pypgame
```

Comment: tried it just now through powershell in the 3.7 directory and got this error.
`python3.7 : The term 'python3.7' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ python3.7 -m pip install pygame
+ ~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (python3.7:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException`

Comment: For Windows, I'd specify the full path to the 3.7 python.exe file.

Comment: right now i have the terminal at `PS C:\Users\alexa\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Python 3.7>`. Does it need to be more specific?

Comment: You may have python.exe under there or under a `bin` directory below. I'd try using that.

Comment: Figured it out. It apparently wanted me to type out `./python` instead of just python. Thank you!